# Perl RexEx Replace locks Apache access_log

Tags: linux, bash, apache-http-server, perl

I wanted to clean up my apache server logs, remove all the 301, 404, and so on, and after trying and failing with sed, I used Perl, which worked wonderfully, except... Then Apache no longer logs anything till the service is restarted.

Any idea why that might be, or what I could do to overcome the challenge? I was hoping to make this part of a bash script that runs as a cron job.

Here are a couple examples of what I wanted to execute.

```
perl -pi -e "s/(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) - - (.*) \+0000(.*)HTTP\/1.1\" \d{3} \d{1,8}(.*)/\1 - \2\3\4/" access_log
perl -pi -e "s/.*( 301 | 404 |index\.php\/|Googlebot| \/ |bingbot|Special\:CreateAccount|php\?title\=|POST \/index.php|xlsx.full.min.js|javascript.js| \/\?author\=|Baiduspider).*\n//" access_log
```

Comment: Is it an option to cleanup after logrotation?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, yes, but I am monitoring in real time to see when I text someone a link, what they look at on the site.

Comment: In that case `grep` might make more sense to filter the output.

Comment: This makes sense to me.  Apache must open the file for writing (append), and Perl is messing with the contents of the file.

I wonder if you could copy the file and operate on the copy or rotate the file and start a new one before processing it.  I do wonder though if its possible to add a conditional custom log to Apache to only log 200 requests?

Comment: I tried doing the custom log where you use regular expressions in the `conf` file to define a enviromental variable, then set `env=!ignore_request` but it didn't work. Maybe it was because I have multiple definitions of the `ignore_request` variable, so I can do multiple regular expressions. I just realized that may have unintentionally created an issue. I thought I had to so I could access the `SetEnvIf Request_Status` as well as `SetEnvIf Request_URI` and others. But maybe, I should have just created multiple variables instead of lumping them all into the same.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit log files that are still held open by apache. The perl `-i` flag makes perl rename the log file to a temporary name, open that file, then create and open a new file `access_log`. It puts the edited output into that new file, then closes the temporary file, which is still the one that apache writes to. However, the file no longer appears in the filesystem as no-one has it open under the new name, and when apache exits, all the file contents will disappear.

The clean way to edit logs is to get apache to restart with a new log file, after renaming the old file.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how the process works. Would it be different if I used `sed`?

Comment: `sed -i` does it slightly differently, creating and writing to a new temporary file, then renames this to the name of the original file, effectively deleting the original file. But the result is the same: apache keeps writing to the old file which is no longer visible in the filesystem.